# Open, Protect, Save and Close Multiple Files in a Folder

Tags: excel, vba

I need to run Excel VBA code that will open 50 .xlsx files in a single folder, one by one I suppose, protect the sheet, save and close.

I would love a dialog that tells me how many files were found to first confirm the number of files in the folder.

Here's the code that has been suggested to open, protect, save and close a single file.

```vb
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    ChDir "G:\Folder\Subfolder\Projects"
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "G:\Folder\Subfolder\Projects\Filename.xlsx"
            ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
        , AllowFormattingCells:=True
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vba+loop+over+files+in+folder

Comment: Where do you get this list of ~50 or so files?  You can certainly wrap your macro code in a loop that will open and close each file in turn, but the specifics depend on how you identify the right set of. Xlsx files.  Also the ChDir is unnecessary and the last statement should be ActiveWorkbook, not ActiveWindow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
Sub protect_excel_files_sheets_in_folder()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim file_path As String, work_file As String, file_types As String
Dim work_folder As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .ButtonName = "Select"
    .Show

    If .SelectedItems.Count <> 1 Then
        GoTo CleanExit
    End If

    work_folder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

file_types = "*.xls*"

work_file = Dir(work_folder & file_types)

Do While work_file <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=work_folder & work_file)
        For Each sheet In wb.Sheets
            sheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True
        Next
        Sheets(0).Activate
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    work_file = Dir
Loop
CleanExit:
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I just happen to have something similar, to password protect and unprotect all file and sheets, in my library. I took out the password part and it should work for you.

Comment: Hi, Harry.  You're quickly becoming my hero of the day.  I'm getting an error when I debug.  Do While work_file <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=work_folder & work_file)
    HERE>>>    For Each sheet In wb.Sheets sheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True
        Next
        Sheets(0).Activate
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    work_file = Dir
Loop

Comment: What error did you get? I think may have messed up the CR when pasting the code in. on the "sheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True" line. I have fixed the code.

Comment: @HarryLee  I'd suggest changing the line `Exit Sub` to `GoTo CleanExit` so that you can avoid any issues caused by leaving Excel in the `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` state

Comment: @Glenn G you are right! I missed that one.